# Android return value in AsyncTask onPostExecute using Interface

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-ksoap2

in this below code i want to return value from `AsyncTask` with using an Interface. but i get wrong value and i can not return correct value from `onPostExecute`.

i'm developed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a) tutorials with my code. i can not use correctly with that.

Interface:

```
public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(String output);
}
```

`Ksoap` Main class:

```
public class WSDLHelper  implements AsyncResponse{
    public SoapObject request;

    private String Mainresult;

    public String call(SoapObject rq){

        ProcessTask p =new ProcessTask(rq);
        String tmp = String.valueOf(p.execute());

        p.delegate = this;

        return Mainresult;
    }


    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {

        this.Mainresult = output;
    }
}
class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void > {
    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

    SoapObject req1;
    private String result;
    public ProcessTask(SoapObject rq) {
        req1 = rq;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(this.req1);

        AndroidHttpTransport transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(Strings.URL_TSMS);
        transport.debug = true;

        try {
            transport.call(Strings.URL_TSMS + this.req1.getName(), envelope);
            this.result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (result.equals(String.valueOf(Integers.CODE_USER_PASS_FALSE))) {
            try {
                throw new TException(PublicErrorList.USERNAME_PASSWORD_ERROR);
            } catch (TException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        Log.e("------------++++++++++++++++-----------", this.result);

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    /* super.onPostExecute(result);*/
        delegate.processFinish(this.result);
    }

}
```

please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: change the return type of `doInBackground()`, `onPostExecute()`, and then return your object using `return` statement

Answer (score 2):

That can't work. You are creating and executing the AsyncTask (asynchronously!) and then call return Mainresult (synchronously!) when it hasn't received the result yet. The solution is to **remove the redundant class WSDLHelper and access ProcessTask directly**

Beside that, you're using AsyncTask incorrectly (saving the result in a class variable instead of passing it as a parameter). Here's the full version:

```
public class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

SoapObject req1;

public ProcessTask(SoapObject rq, AsyncResponse delegate) {
    req1 = rq;
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(this.req1);

    AndroidHttpTransport transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(Strings.URL_TSMS);
    transport.debug = true;

    String result = null;
    try {
        transport.call(Strings.URL_TSMS + this.req1.getName(), envelope);
        result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
    } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
        Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
    }

    if (result != null && result.equals(String.valueOf(Integers.CODE_USER_PASS_FALSE))) {
        try {
            throw new TException(PublicErrorList.USERNAME_PASSWORD_ERROR);
        } catch (TException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    Log.e("------------++++++++++++++++-----------", result);

    return result;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
/* super.onPostExecute(result);*/
    delegate.processFinish(result);
}

}
```

Now you would execute ProcessTask from outside like this, which will make sure you **receive the result asynchronously**:

```
new ProcessTask(rq, new AsyncResponse() {
    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        // do whatever you want with the result
    }
}).execute();
```

Comment: Thanks sir. how can i develop `call` method in `WSDLHelper`? i get error in `Contsructor` in `ProcessTask p =new ProcessTask(rq); `i'm change that to `public String call(SoapObject rq){

        ProcessTask p =new ProcessTask(rq,this);
        /*String tmp = String.valueOf(p.execute());
        p.delegate = this;*/

        return MainResult;
    }` but thats not correct.

Comment: Oh actually, I haven't seen your "p.delegate = this". That's wrong in so many ways ... You haven't understood the concept of interfaces. You're executing an AsyncTask and expect to immediately return its result. It's asynchronous, so that's impossible! I will update my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry sir. i'm develop you update code to http://paste.debian.net/120158/ . but thats wrong and return `NullPointerException`.

Comment: ***REMOVE*** WSDLHelper. ***Do not return "Mainresult"***, it's null because ProcessTask returns its result asynchronously! ***Handle the result INSIDE processFinish()***. If you're not able to grasp this, you must read [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) -- no one can help you otherwise.

Comment: Excuse me. i read that link before your send topic but i'm using `call` method form `WSDLHelper` in all of project and i must be return result from it to use other methods and i can not **Remove** `WSDLHelper`. can i return result from it after get output with `processFinish`.for example: `LoginFields loginSoapParser = tsms.SoapParser(wsdlHelper.call(tsms.SoapObjectRequest));` please help me thanks

Comment: No you can't. processFinish() runs in a different thread -- not the one that called wsdlHelper.call(...), so call(...) returns before processFinish() is executed. You can only do something **inside processFinish()**. You can either directly update any views there (call setText(output) on a TextView, for example) or pass the result to other objects implementing AsyncResponse and do something there. I can't help you further, I was more thorough than most people on StackOverflow would be. You're on your own now.

Answer (score 0):

Your result will always be null, because you return null in the `doInBackground()` method. The value you return in `doInBackground()` will be passed to onPostExecute(). Change your `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` to `AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>`, and return the result. This will call `onPostExecute(String result)` with the correct result.

Perhaps this link might help you a bit: http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/using-asynctask.html