# Android return value from processFinish in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

in this below code i want to pass data from `processFinish` method to use that in outside class but i can not fix problem and i can not return value from `processFinish` in `call` function.

```
public class WSDLHelper  implements AsyncResponse{
    public SoapObject request;

    private String MainResult;

    public String call(SoapObject rq){

        new ProcessTask(rq, this).execute();
        return MainResult;
    }

    @Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        MainResult = output;
    }
}

class ProcessTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,  String> {
    public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

    SoapObject req1;

    public ProcessTask(SoapObject rq, AsyncResponse delegate) {
        req1 = rq;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(this.req1);

        AndroidHttpTransport transport = new AndroidHttpTransport(Strings.URL_TSMS);
        transport.debug = true;

        String result = null;
        try {
            transport.call(Strings.URL_TSMS + this.req1.getName(), envelope);
            result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            Log.e("" , ex.getMessage());
        }

        if (result.equals(String.valueOf(Integers.CODE_USER_PASS_FALSE))) {
            try {
                throw new TException(PublicErrorList.USERNAME_PASSWORD_ERROR);
            } catch (TException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        delegate.processFinish(result);
    }
}
```

please help me to develop `call` method to return `output` value to outside class. thanks

Comment: Is the delegate null on onPostExecute? Because if not then it's working as intended.

Comment: @PedroOliveira yes thats null. how to resolve that?

Comment: [Same exact question answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25759586/2964379). Mahdi, please understand that *return MainResult;* **runs before** *MainResult = output;* and therefore call(...) will always return null, no matter what you do.

Comment: And both questions are actually reposts of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758236/android-asynctask-dont-return-correct-result).

Answer (score 0):

There you are implementing AsyncResponce.
so
Replace

```
new ProcessTask(rq, new AsyncResponse() {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String output) {
                MainResult = output;
            }
        }).execute();
```

By

```
new ProcessTask(rq, this).execute();
```

Then your class `overrided` method p`rocessFinish(String output)` will call.

And use your value at processFinish() rather than value retured by call( ) method.

Comment: do not resolve problem for `new ProcessTask(rq, this).execute();return MainResult;` with this implemented method `@Override
    public void processFinish(String output) {
        MainResult = output;
    }`

Comment: R u debugged your code is there any Exception?

Comment: yes. thats return null

Comment: There you are returning value from your call(...) method.
Please use value on processFinished().

Comment: my problem don't resolve and `call` method must return. can you paste correct code to post?

Comment: It's
AsyncTask functionality you can't return it with call method.

Comment: i know it i'm using `AsyncResponse` as an Interface to get result and pass data from `call` method.

Comment: can you help me to get value from Interface and return value from it? my post **updated**

Answer (score 0):

ProcessTask is an async task, so when u invoke `call`method, u will get `null` when `return MainResult`, becz it has not been set by `processFinish`method yet.